# Is SSL secure against these forms of attack?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography

Alice and Bob need to communicate important business information. Alice creates a certificate authority and properly secures it in a locked safe. She makes two certificates, one that identifies Alice and one that identifies Bob. Alice then sets up a server accepting SSL connections using her certificate, and only accepts clients using Bob's client certificate. The connection is done over the internet using an IP address, not a DNS hostname.

Without compromising Alice or Bob's certificates, are the following attack vectors possible?

1. Can Chuck send a message to either Alice or Bob, pretending to be the other?
2. Can Eve understand any part of their communication?

And lastly, should one of those two certificates be compromised, how can it be revoked?

Comment: Possibly better-suited for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/, as this isn't really a programming issue.

Comment: Agree with @OliCharlesworth but I would point out that you should be a bit more specific about what `Alice makes two certificates` exactly means!

Comment: @MikyDinescu I mean she uses that certificate authority to create two SSL certificates - one for the server which is not unlike those we use for HTTPS, and another for the client.

Comment: I think you're right about crypto.stackexchange.com. Is there a way to migrate?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Is it?

Comment: @configurator - the process of "making" a certificate implies a request made by the certificate recipient and a _generate_ step performed by the issuer (cert. authority). If Alice makes both the requests than she will "own" both her cert and the one she gives Bob which means that she can impersonate Bob.

Comment: @MikyDinescu, she could issue the cert from a CSR given by Bob without having his private key. Of course, all of this distinction is quite pointless in this example, since Alice controls the CA altogether, so she can impersonate whoever she likes in the context of that CA.

Comment: @NickJohnson: It isn't though I can see why you'd think it is, I did try to specify it in isolated terms which makes it sound pedagogical. What it really is is my attempt to implement secure private communication over a public network without using the tools currently available which are both expensive _and_ insecure. (But required by law)

Comment: @Bruno: Indeed, Alice is all-powerful in this context anyway. Bob doesn't even know where the power button is, so Alice sets up his entire system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security, not programming. As such it should be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specified about the certificates and the SSL version and options, but usually certificates are used to promise that a public key of some site is authentic (and therefore only the site has the private key) - this is what CAs come to deal with.

The certificate is not a secret.

If you mean that both Alice and Bob now know the authentic public keys of each other, it still doesn't mean that only Alice and Bob know the public key of each other!

So to your first questions:

If Chuck knows the public key too - he can encrypt messages for both Alice and Bob. However, if he gets back some response, encrypted with Alice/Bob public key, he should not be able to decrypt it.

However, if client authentication is used (you didn't specify which SSL scheme is used), then the server will detect it on the handshake step, while Chuck doesn't know the private key.
See the handshake procedure http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc%2Fsy10660_.htm
. The client certificate request from the server is optional.

And to the second:
If they have authentic keys, than they can communicate securely. Eve cannot decrypt the content of the message (except with negligible probability), and can only learn information by side channels (e.g. timing, the volume of the traffic).

Comment: Yes, when I said that Alice "only accepts clients using Bob's client certificate" I meant that client authentication is used. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What about revocation? How can I implement it so that Alice can revoke her own certificate should it be compromised?

Comment: I believe Alice can use CRL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation).

Comment: Yes, the default answer is to use a CRL or an OCSP.